Why is $(this).text() not showing value in <input> tag when using $('#table tbody tr').filter function?
I am developing a functionality to filter table content based on text box input.
Here is my code.
HTML code:
<div style="overflow: auto;">
     <div style="margin: 20px; display: flex; justify-content: space-around;">
          <span>Product: <span id="btnawfproduct"></span></span>
          <div>Filter: <input id="filteraliasdesc" type="text"></div>
          <button id = "btnupdatealiasdesc" class="btn btn--dark">Update All</button>
     </div>
     <table id="editaliastable" style="table-layout: fixed; width: 100%;">
        <thead>
             <tr>
                  <th>Metric</th>
                  <th>Metric Alias</th>
                  <th>Metric Description</th>
             </tr>
        </thead>
     </table>
</div>

JS code:
$(document).on('keyup', '#filteraliasdesc', function(){
    var searchText = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $('#editaliastable tbody tr').filter(function(){
      var rowText = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
      console.log('rowText --> ', rowText) //This is not showing input type='text' value
      if(rowText.indexOf(searchText) === -1){
            $(this).hide();
        } else {
            $(this).show();
        }
    });
});

$(document).on("click", ".editaliasdesc", function () {
    const table = $('#editaliastable');
    $('#btnawfproduct').text(awf_metric_alias[0]['productname']);
    var metric_alias = awf_metric_alias[1]['metric_alias'];
    var table_rows = ''
    for(var i = 0; i < metric_alias.length; i++)
        table_rows += `<tr>
                        <td><input type='checkbox' class ="chkupdatealias" style='transform: scale(1.5);'>${metric_alias[i].metric}</td>
                        <td><input type='text' style='width: 100%;' value = '${metric_alias[i].metric_alias}'></td>
                        <td><textarea style='width: 100%;'>${metric_alias[i].description}</textarea></td>
                     </tr>`;
    table.append('<tbody>' + table_rows + '</tbody>');
});


Problem:
The keyup function is not filtering the value in element <td><input type='text' style='width: 100%;' value = '${metric_alias[i].metric_alias}'></td> i.e the metric alias column in table.
Please advice, Thanks.

Please also include the generated table HTML in your question.

I dont see the html class .editaliasdesc that is referenced in the javascript. Is it missing?

@RAllen, html code is already added in this question, data is generated dynamically, I have added generated table image for reference.

You expect wrong behaviour. .text returns value of text nodes, not values of input elements. You explicitly must get $('input', $(this)).val():


$(document).ready(function () {
  let row = $('table tr');

  console.log('.text returns', row.text());
  console.log('.val returns', $('input', row).val());
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table><tr><td>Input field: <input value="123"/></td></tr></table>




The .text() method will not return the value properties of <input> elements.
If you want to include those, you'll need to extract them from the .value property.


$('tbody tr').each(function() {
  const row = $(this);
  const rowText = [
    row.text(),
    ...row.find(':text').map((_, { value }) => value),
  ].join(' ').toLowerCase();
  
  console.log('row text:', JSON.stringify(rowText));
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" />a</td>
      <td><input type="text" value="a" /></td>
      <td><textarea>new desc for a</textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" />b</td>
      <td><input type="text" value="bb" /></td>
      <td><textarea>sdsdcsd</textarea></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>



